# If "null=True", which is stored in DB, "NULL" or "empty values"?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, null

I created **the django model "User"** with **"null=True"** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):                   # Here
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

Then, I intuitively thought **"NULL"** is stored in **DB** when **an empty value is saved** as shown below because of **"null=True"**:

[image]

But, when I checked [**the django documentation about "NULL"**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#null), it says:

> If True, Django will store empty values as NULL in the database.

So, as the documentation says, if **"null=True"** and **an empty value is saved** as shown above, is **"an empty value"** stored in **DB**  instead of **"NULL"**?

Comment: You are reading it in the wrong direction: if the form provides an *empty* value, it will store `NULL`, not the other way around.

Comment: So the parameter is named badly. It could have been `store_empty_as_null` or `use_nulls_for_empty_fields`

Comment: as long as i remember, it stores `NULL` in DB if you don't provide an empty value

Answer (score 2):

> So, as the documentation says, "empty values" is stored in DB instead of `NULL` if `null=True`?

**No**. If you provide an empty value, for example in a `ModelForm` leave a *form* field empty, Django will by default store it as `NULL` in the database, so it is the other way around. So it means that for this it will normally *not* store an empty string, but always `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

No, if **"null=True"** and **an empty value is saved**, **"NULL"** is stored in **DB** instead of **"an empty value"**.

For example, there is **the django model "User"** with **"null=True"** as shown below:

```py
# "myapp/models.py"

from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):                   # Here
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

Then, you saved **an empty value**:

[image]

Now, **"NULL"** is stored in **"myapp_user" table** in **SQLite** as shown below:

[image]